# can't find a register in class 'CREG' while reloading 'asm' - memcpy inline asm

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I am trying to make an earlier verion Linux got compiled, you can download the source code from git://github.com/azru0512/linux-0.12.git. While compiling ''kernel/blk_drv/ramdisk.c'', I got error message below,

```
ramdisk.c:36:10: error: can't find a register in class 'CREG' while reloading 'asm'
ramdisk.c:40:10: error: can't find a register in class 'CREG' while reloading 'asm'
ramdisk.c:36:10: error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints
ramdisk.c:40:10: error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints
```

What in ramdisk.c are,

```
  if (CURRENT-> cmd == WRITE) {
    (void) memcpy(addr,
            CURRENT->buffer,
            len);
  } else if (CURRENT->cmd == READ) {
    (void) memcpy(CURRENT->buffer,
            addr,
            len);
  } else
    panic("unknown ramdisk-command");
```

And the memcpy is,

```
extern inline void * memcpy(void * dest,const void * src, int n)
{
__asm__("cld\n\t"
  "rep\n\t"
  "movsb"
  ::"c" (n),"S" (src),"D" (dest)
  :"cx","si","di");
return dest;
}
```

I guess it's memcpy (include/string.h) inline asm problem, so I remove the clobber list from it but without luck. Could you help me to find out what's going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful to show ramdisk.c line 36-40 and the surrounding code

Comment: I removed the clobber list. Not sure what you mean "Turning on optimization", but I try -O[0..3] without luck. If I remove the inline prefix, then I get "multiple definition of `memcpy'" error.

Comment: memcpy is already in a header, i.e., include/string.h.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong: The definition belongs to a *.c source file, in the header only the declaration `void * memcpy(void * dest,const void * src, int n);` should remain

Answer (score 3):

GCC's syntax for this has changed / evolved a bit.

You must now specify each of the special target registers as an output operand:

```
...("...instructions..."
   : "=c"(n), "=S"(src), "=D"(dest)
```

and then additionally as the *same* registers as source operands:

```
   : "0"(n), "1"(src), "2"(dest)
```

and finally you need to clobber "memory" (I can't remember offhand if this affects condition codes, if so you would also need "cc"):

```
   : "memory")
```

Next, because this instruction should not be moved or deleted, you need to use either `volatile` or `__volatile__` (I'm not entirely sure why but without this the instructions were deleted, in my test-case).

Last, it's no longer a good idea to attempt to override `memcpy` because gcc "knows" how to implement the function.  You can override gcc's knowledge with `-fno-builtin`.

This compiles (for me anyway, with a somewhat old gcc on an x86-64 machine):

```
extern inline void * memcpy(void * dest,const void * src, int n)
{
    __asm__ volatile("cld\n\t"
        "rep\n\tmovsb\n\t"
        : "=c" (n), "=S" (src), "=D" (dest)
        : "0" (n), "1" (src), "2" (dest)
        : "memory", "cc");
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your reply, I learned much. I found there is ANOTHER memcpy defined as a macro in include/asm/memroy.h. After commenting out that memcpy, the ramdisk.c error is gone even doesn't remove the clobber list in the memcpy defined in include/string.h.

Comment: This makes me confused, why remove include/asm/memory.h but leave include/string.h alone makes the error disappeared. What's the correct solution on writing the inline asm? Does no compiler error mean everything is fine?

Comment: Lack of a compiler error does not guarantee that all is well; it just means that you get to work on the next level of problem. :-)  Anyway if you're going to delve this deeply into implementation specifics, you're going to have to be very specific about implementations, since gcc 2.x, 3.x, and 4.x vary, and installations may point include files somewhere other than `/usr/include` (e.g., perhaps you are getting headers from `/usr/local/include`).

Answer (score 0):

This exact problem & its reasons are discussed on GCC's bugzilla  :

[Bug 43998 - inline assembler: can't set clobbering for input register](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43998)

gcc wont allow input & output registers as clobbers. 
If you corrupt input register, do a dummy output to same register :

```
unsigned int operation;
unsigned int dummy;
asm ("cpuid" : "=a" (dummy) : "0" ( operation) :);
```