# Achieve window function InterlockedExchange in Linux

Tags: c, linux, assembly

In this link [achieve GCC cas function for version 4.1.2 and earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598339/achieve-gcc-cas-function-for-version-4-1-2-and-earlier) I ask a question to use `compare_and_swap` function to achieve the Built-in function `__sync_fetch_and_add` here is my final code, run well in x86 and x64 (tested on *CentOS 5.0 32bit* and *CentOS 7 64bit* ).

---

Here is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static unsigned long  count = 0;

int sync_add_and_fetch(int* reg, int oldval, int incre) 
{
    register char result;
#ifdef __i386__
    __asm__ volatile ("lock; cmpxchgl %3, %0; setz %1" 
                     : "=m"(*reg), "=q" (result) 
                     : "m" (*reg), "r" (oldval + incre), "a" (oldval) 
                     : "memory");
    return result;
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
    __asm__ volatile ("lock; cmpxchgq %3, %0; setz %1" 
                     : "=m"(*reg), "=q" (result) 
                     : "m" (*reg), "r" (newval + incre), "a" (oldval) 
                     : "memory");
    return result;
#else
    #error:architecture not supported and gcc too old
#endif

}


void *test_func(void *arg)
{
    int i = 0;
    int result = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 2000; ++i)
    {
        result = 0;
        while(0 == result)
        {
            result = sync_add_and_fetch((int *)&count, count, 1);
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t id[10];
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, test_func, NULL);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        pthread_join(id[i], NULL);
    }
    //10*2000=200000
    printf("%u\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I have another question, how to implement function `InterlockedExchange` in Linux, [**InterlockedExchange**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-interlockedexchangepointer) just like the code above, have a `__i386__` and `__x86_64__` version. Just use the code above the parameter type not match, and maybe the assembly code will be rewritten.

Comment: You don't need separate i386 and x86_64 versions; both should be using `cmpxchgl` because `int` is 32 bit in both ISAs.  [@Timothy's answer on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598339/achieve-gcc-cas-function-for-version-4-1-2-and-earlier#51600261) already pointed this out.

Comment: Also, that `sync_add_and_fetch` only makes one attempt to CAS, so the function name doesn't reflect what it does.  Use `lock xadd` so you never need to retry.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for your advice,I try to use lock xadd to achieve the sync_add_and_fetch ,how to rewrite it ? when I simple replace it ,gcc tells :number of operands mismatch for xadd.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks ,I test for wrong machine,they both 32 bit centos, I am now install centosx64,and when I operate long or unsigned long,I have to write another function?

Comment: Yes, you need another function with another name with different types for the inputs and return value.  `l` and `ll` suffixes are probably good, or maybe `p` for `void *`.  That's probably easier than trying to use C11 generic overloads (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic), and your ancient compiler probably doesn't support it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange is easy; you don't have to return any status or anything.  It [`xchg`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/XCHG.html) always swaps, so you just have to return the old value and/or a status [like for cmpxchg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822854/c-inline-assembly-getting-operand-size-mismatch-when-using-cmpxchg#49839296).

```
static inline
int sync_xchg(int *p, int newval)
{
    // xchg mem,reg has an implicit lock prefix
    asm volatile("xchg %[newval], %[mem]"
        : [mem] "+m" (*p), [newval] "+r" (newval)  // read/write operands
        :
        : "memory" // compiler memory barrier, giving us seq-cst memory ordering
    );
    return newval;
}
```

It might be better to use `int32_t`, but int is 32 bits in all relevant ABIs.
Also, this asm works for any size of integer.  GCC will pick a 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit register, and that will imply that operand-size for xchg.  (You only need a suffix like `addl` when there's no register operand, e.g. `lock; addl $1, (%0)`)

Anyway, I tested this and it compiles correctly with [gcc4.1.2 on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'//+static+inline%0Aint+sync_xchg(int+*p,+int+newval)+%0A%7B%0A++++//+xchg+mem,reg+has+an+implicit+lock+prefix%0A++++asm+volatile(%22xchg+%25%5Bnewval%5D,+%25%5Bmem%5D%22%0A++++++++:+%5Bmem%5D+%22%2Bm%22+(*p),+%5Bnewval%5D+%22%2Br%22+(newval)%0A++++++++:%0A++++++++:+%22memory%22+//+compiler+memory+barrier,+giving+us+seq-cst+memory+ordering%0A++++)%3B%0A++++return+newval%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g412,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.1.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g412,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-m32+-fomit-frame-pointer',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.1.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).  I don't have access to gcc4.1.1, but hopefully `"+m"` and `[named]` asm memory operands weren't new in that release.

`+m` makes it *much* easier to write a bulletproof swap function.  e.g. no risk of gcc choosing two different memory locations for the same variable as an input vs. as an output.

`gcc -O3` output from gcc4.1.2:

```
# 32-bit: -m32 -fomit-frame-pointer
sync_xchg(int*, int):
    movl    4(%esp), %edx
    movl    8(%esp), %eax
    xchg %eax, (%edx)
    ret                   # returns in EAX


# 64-bit: just -O3
sync_xchg(int*, int):
    xchg %esi, (%rdi)
    movl    %esi, %eax
    ret                    # returns in EAX
```

I also checked that this asm actually assembles, using a newer gcc and clicking the `11010` binary button on Godbolt.  Fun fact: because GAS accepts xchg mem,reg or xchg reg,mem, you can compile this function with AT&T or Intel syntax (`-masm=intel`).  Your other functions won't work, though.