# Posix Equivalent for InterlockedExchange

Tags: c, posix, atomic

What is the Posix equivalent to the Windows `InterlockedExchange`?

I have found the equivalent for `InterlockedCompareExchange` (i.e. `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`) but not simple exchange. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617338/achieve-window-function-interlockedexchange-in-linux) that gave a solution in assembly, but I need a cross platform/architecture C solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to C2011 `stdatomic.h`, then I believe [`atomic_exchange`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.7.3) is what you are looking for.

I am not aware of any other standardized equivalent.  In particular, the current version of POSIX does *not* mandate the presence of `stdatomic.h` (which is optional in C2011), and no version of POSIX has defined its own atomic operations, only higher-level thread synchronization operations (`pthread_mutex_*` for instakce).

Comment: Thanks @zwol. I will try it out.

Comment: Seems everything blows up when I include that header:
```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/stdatomic.h:42:9: error: ‘_Atomic’ does not name a type
   42 | typedef _Atomic signed char atomic_schar;
      |         ^~~~~~~
```
So perhaps I can't use it.

Comment: @Nick Which compiler and compiler options?

Comment: @NickBanks Seconding n.m. -- that error message looks to me like, somehow, headers that are only meant to be used by GCC 9.x are being read by some other compiler.

Comment: I'm using GitHub CodeSpaces and letting cmake pick. So perhaps it's picking clang.

Comment: I regret to say I can't help you with either codespaces or cmake. However, I can tell you that current versions of clang should have their own (different) copy of stdatomic.h, and that if I take the error message at face value it means the compiler you're using, whatever it is, doesn't support C2011 atomics at all.